# Error in Text Function in Calculate in Power Bi Using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get average salary from Employee depending upon the # of rows returned.

```
_m = 
IF (
    CALCULATE ( AVERAGE( 'Employee'[Salary] )  = BLANK ()
    ),0, CALCULATE ( AVERAGE(  'Employee'[Salary] ))
)
```

Now i want to do the same for Employee Name as well

```
_m = 
IF (
    CALCULATE ( Value( 'Employee'[Name] )  = BLANK ()
    ),"", CALCULATE ( Value(  'Employee'[Name] ))
)
```

**Update:**

But here i am getting error cannot find Employee[Name].
However the same above function works well when i exchange value with average.

Comment: Based on your error message I would say you dont have a column `Name` in your `Employee` table. But without any details or the table design I can just assume.

Comment: What is the second measure supposed to return? A single name?

Comment: Yes either a employee name or blank

Answer (score 0):

The [`VALUE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/value-function-dax) is used to convert text to a number. You probably meant to use [`VALUES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/values-function-dax) instead, which returns a list of unique values in the column.

I'd suggest the following:

```
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Employee'[Name], "" )
```

This is equivalent to

```
 IF ( HASONEVALUE ( 'Employee'[Name] ), VALUES ( 'Employee'[Name] ), "" )
```